# Router and Switch MAC Address

Tags: router, switch, mac-address

There is a MAC address for each router and switch interface.

But, is there a MAC address that represents the whole device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The MAC address it the out-facing hardware address of any & all network interfaces; if you have 2 NICs each has its own MAC address.
The device behind that, strictly, has no MAC address at all.

[*Edit* NIC is Network Interface Card]

Comment: I am trying to discover a router. To do this I used the MAC address of the managment interface. But even with this MAC address my application show me that the router has no ports.

Comment: I have no idea how you would 'find' a device from its MAC address... it seems a bit 'cart before horse' without an IP address to hang on to. [others may know better, so I'm cautious]